# How to calculate how many rotations are needed to roll a X thick strip around a core?

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic-progressions

I'm trying to understand how many rotations/spins I need to put a given length around a core.

My specific problem is:
I have a 30m long strip 1mm thick that I will roll around a rotation core that has a lever mechanism.
At start the core OD is 50mm.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZvlR.gif)

I don't have any idea how to calculate this.

Comment: It depends on the thickness of the strip.

Comment: @tonyk thanks I've edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am assuming that your $OD$ means the diameter of the rotation core. Perhaps this would be obvious to an engineer!)

The cross-sectional (or "side-on") area of the strip is $30$m$\times 1$mm$=30000$ mm$^2$. And the cross-sectional area of the core is $625\pi$ mm$^2$. If the completed roll has total radius $R$ mm, then its cross-sectional area is $\pi R^2$. But we know its cross-sectional area is $(30000+625\pi)$ mm$^2$. Therefore
$$\pi R^2=30000+625\pi$$
$$R=\sqrt{30000/\pi+625}\approx 100.87$$

Subtracting the radius of the core, we get that the thickness of the wound strip is $R-
25\approx 75.87$ mm. Therefore there are $\approx 75.87$ windings.

In real life, this is of course unreasonably precise; expect about $76$ windings.

Comment: Thank you so much :D